# How to fix "NA" quantile when using dplyr::ntile() function

Tags: r, dplyr, quantile

I'm using the `dplyr::ntile()` function to split my data into 4 groups. However, `ntile()` also produced an `"NA"` category. Further inspection of that data point tells me that the `"NA"` produced from `ntile()` should really go into the 1st quartile, but I'm not sure how to do this.

> Value: 146.8447
>
> First quartile defined by `ntile()`: (147,385]

I suspect this is a rounding error of some sort but I did not see any arguments to pass into `ntile()` to try to get around this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example?

Comment: have you tried adding na.rm=TRUE

Comment: @Laurence_jj To clarify, there are no NA values in the dataset.

Comment: @JamesMartherus Unfortunately I cannot share the data but if I do `table(data)` then the breakpoints from `ntile()` show as follows:         
`(147,385] (385,450] (450,503] (503,811] 
       26        27        27        26 ` but this is not correct since there is one observation missing which should belong to the first grouping

Comment: @jnguyen you don’t need to share your actual data, you could create a toy dataset that looks similar to yours. That would allow people to reproduce this behavior and tinker with it to find a fix.

Comment: @JamesMartherus I'm not sure why but I can't get this to work (i.e. am getting normal behaviour with `ntile()`) on a toy dataset, so perhaps no one can really help me... I was just hoping that someone may have encountered a similar problem before and would be able to share what they learned, but I can go the more traditional routes as well.